# What is a lite model in Deep Learning?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow-lite

I wanted to know what is a lite model?

I know that a model that is easier to train and has fewer neurons is a lite model but how to say how much are these "fewer neurons"??

If I use a pre-trained model and add two Dense layers to it (where I freeze those pre-trained model layers and train only the Final two layers) can I call these a lite model as it is faster to train and inference results are also fast???

Comment: [TensorFlow Lite](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite) is an open source deep learning framework for on-device inference. It has little to do with model size.

There is no objective threshold that separate small / large models.

Comment: @RaidasGrisk thnx for the reply